# NextJs application build with Bazel

Tags: next.js, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

During a Bazel build of a NextJs project I get a error related to cjs react.

```
Generating static pages (0/3)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.exports.useContext (apps/landing/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
```

The BUILD file for the package looks like this:

```
load("@landing-npm//next:index.bzl", "next")

filegroup(
    name = "config",
    srcs = [
        ".eslintrc.json",
        "next.config.js",
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "package.json",
        "tsconfig.json",
        "yarn.lock",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "project",
    srcs = glob([
        "pages/**/*.ts",
        "pages/**/*.tsx",
        "public/*",
        "styles/*",
    ]),
)

next(
    name = "build",
    args = [
        "build",
        "apps/landing",
    ],
    data =
        [
            "config",
            "project",
            "@landing-npm//:node_modules",
        ],
)
```

Furthermore, the WORKSPACE has loaded the rules_nodejs with a repository of node_version = 16.15.1 and yarn_version = 1.22.19

The apps/landing is a project created with the next cli create --typescript default configuration.

I'm passing all the node_modules dependencies as data, so I don't think it is related to missing dependencies. Does anyone have some ideas on what could be creating this error and how it could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9022 .
and move npm/yarn packages installation at project root folder.

```
yarn_install(
    name = "npm",
    exports_directories_only = True,
    package_json = "//:package.json",
    yarn_lock = "//:yarn.lock",
)
```